# Old switch from AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get Old switch from AppCompatActivity without extending our class from AppCompatActivity ?

[image]

Comment: No one is requiring you to extend the AppCompatActivity class in your app, but the widget styles are control by the base SDK, not the support libraries

Comment: so without change SDK it is possible ?

Comment: You can always apply a different `style` attribute in the XML onto the switch, but I don't know what the correct value is

Comment: i have 2 project with SDK 25, and they have different style of switch

Comment: Please add screenshots of what exactly you're looking for. And it's the API on the actual device that matters, not exactly your compileSdk

Comment: screen added @cricket_007

Comment: press the delete link under your question instead, as long as it is visibile you can not deface it.